# Issue with changing working directories and using imports in Python

Tags: python, directory

I have a file structure like this:

```
application
├── scripts
│   └── script1.py
├── utils
│   └── util1.py
├── main.py
```

Now I want to be able to import `util1.py` from `script1.py` so I decided to change the directory and use imports in `script1.py` like so:

```
import sys
import os
from os.path import dirname, abspath
os.chdir(dirname(dirname((__file__))))
from utils import util1
```

if I were to print the current directory using `os.listdir()` it would show the 2 folders and `main.py`, however it still says that there is no module named `util`. Am I using the `os.chdir` wrongly, or is there something else wrong with my code? I would like to be able to easily access modules from the same parent directory of application without going through too much hassle, since I use quite a lot of them.

Comment: try this from .utils import util1

Comment: Don't change the working directory to import modules. Either use packages, relative imports or add to the [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path)